# What is the openssl API to configure the Heartbeat idle timeout

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I am using a openssl library to implement tls server.
How to configure the Heartbeat request timeout and retry count using openssl API to control the keepalive message flow?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you really do mean TLS as you said and not DTLS. Using heartbeats in TLS is quite unusual, although OpenSSL does support it in version 1.0.2. That support is removed from OpenSSL 1.1.0 so, for that reason, I would advise against using it in a new application. Use TCP keep alives instead.

The Heartbeat API is really quite simple. You can do three things:

1) Send a heartbeat using `SSL_heartbeat()`

2) Find out if a previously sent heartbeat is still pending a response using `SSL_get_tlsext_heartbeat_pending()`

and

3) Set the Heartbeat mode to disallow the peer from sending heartbeat requests using `SSL_set_tlsext_heartbeat_no_requests()`

Anything else is up to the application. Retries should not be necessary in TLS because it is designed to run over a reliable transport layer. If the connection is alive, it will get there. If it isn't, it won't. The TCP layer will handle retransmission of lost packets. Timeouts should also really be done at the TCP layer. If the TCP connection times out the SSL connection will fail.

Comment: it is supported . see `enable-heartbeats` arg.

Comment: Note that I was explicitly talking about heartbeats in TLS being removed in 1.1.0 - not heartbeats in DTLS. The `enable-heartbeats` option in 1.1.0 is for DTLS only.

Comment: dude did you use it ever?

Comment: Nobody uses TLS heartbeats. That's why it was removed. The CHANGES entry for its removal is here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/201b305a2409d9eb13b5e4bfbd4967e04e155a60/CHANGES#L1066-L1069

Comment: only option if you need to send data after 2 hours of empty connection.in my case it's over vpn. if thread is stalled over two hours it wont send anything after that regards of keepalive .`SSL_heartbeat` used  to solve this. it were streaming socket and tls , 1,1,0 .

Comment: The commit that removed this support in TLS is here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/22e3dcb780 That commit first appeared in 1.1.0-pre3, i.e. in one of the pre-releases of 1.1.0 while it was still in alpha/beta testing. If this used to work for you in 1.1.0 then plausibly you were using one of the early pre-release versions.